# How do I make a message collector in discord.js to have multiple responses according to the message the user sent?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a start command for a currency bot. I'm trying to make a message collector, which asks for collecting for this certain user. And depending on the user's response, it would have different responses.

- If the user replies with "yes", the bot will send "cool".
- If the user replies with "no", the bot will send "not cool".
- If the user doesn't reply in 15 seconds or replies something else than "yes" and "no", the bot will send "bruh".

```js
message.channel.send("Yes or no?")
        .then(function (message) {
            const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id,;
            const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
            collector.on('collect', m => {
                if (m == "yes") {
                  message.channel.send("cool")
                } else if (m == "no") {
                  message.channel.send("not cool")
                } else {
                    message.channel.send("bruh")
                } 
                
              })
          })
    }
```

But whatever I say, the bot doesn't respond at all, even in the console. 
 Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Good first question! I think you could even improve it: 1. Please try to reduce the code to make it easier to understand, to narrow down the problem and to make the answer useful to others. 2. Try to optimize the title (it seems you want to send multiple responses at once).

Answer (score 1):

The `message` parameter of the `MessageCollector` returns a message object. What you are currently attempting to do is comparing an object (The parameter `m` that represents the object) with a string - Something that can obviously not be done.
If you would like to compare the collected message to a certain string, you would have to compare its `content` property, that obviously returns the content of the collected message.

#### Final Code:

```
message.channel.send("Yes or no?")
        .then(function (message) {
            const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id,;
            const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
            collector.on('collect', m => {
                if (m.content == "yes") {
                  message.channel.send("cool")
                } else if (m.content == "no") {
                  message.channel.send("not cool")
                } else {
                    message.channel.send("bruh")
                } 
                
              })
          })
    }
```